# Getting contact groups in Android

Tags: android, android-contacts

ALL,
Here is my code:

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Groups.Content_URI, null, null, null, null );
```

Apparently this code throws security exception on my HTC phone.

Does anybody knows how to get group names on Android?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you added permissions in manifest file ? If not then add belew line of code in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```